# Error in uploading a file using java servlet

Tags: java, file, servlets, uploading

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload
Could someone please help me know what exactly is causing this problem

Answer (score 0):

The Classloader can't find the class ServletFileUpload from the Apache Commons API. Check if the JAR is in your Classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Get “`commons-fileupload.jar`” from official website – http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/
and add that